# pip install turicreate is not working in python 3.6 window10

Tags: python-3.x, pip, turi-create

```
pip install Turi-create
```

ERROR

> - Linux x86_64 (including WSL on Windows 10).
> - macOS 10.12+ x86_64.
> - Python 2.7, 3.5, or 3.6.
>
> Other possible causes of this error are:
>
> - Outdated pip version (try `pip install -U pip`).

Comment: can you show the error trace?

Answer (score 1):

The package is called `turicreate`: https://pypi.org/project/turicreate/:

```
pip install turicreate
```

The package doesn't support Windows. The current version [5.2.1](https://pypi.org/project/turicreate/5.2.1/#files) only supports Python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6 on Linux and MacOS. On Windows it works only with WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

Comment: how to install it in windows 10 ?

Comment: @eshwarraj: It does not support windows of any version it seems.